# How to Unzip the file genrated in one folder and add one tag in XML(XMLfile is inside zip) and again zip the file using Java and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am testing one banking application in which one zip file will generate and inside that XML file is located with some tags and I need to add one tag inside XML, again zip the file and save it

Comment: Check [How to add node to xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524697/how-to-add-node-a-structured-xml-at-particular-location-from-java) and [Unzip and zip using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324933/what-is-a-good-java-library-to-zip-unzip-files?rq=1)

Comment: what have u tried so far? where is the code?

Comment: Basically till now we did manually but now trying to Automate. Manual steps 1) open the zip file and put outside xml file 2) inside that xml add one tag at particular place and save and put again in zip and close zip and put in one different folder ..   Here only I am getting stuck

Comment: Thanks Madhan I will apply your code